# how to active popup using jquery after 4 second?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code which shows me a Popup window after 4 seconds, but it does not work at all.

The default result is the popup should not appear. Just after going 4 second.
this is how my folder looks like:

and this is the code review: https://jsfiddle.net/2j6yzt18/

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('#popup1').popup();
  $('#popup2').popup({
    pagecontainer: '#page',
    escape: false
  });
}, 4000);
```

```css
.popup_content {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-width: 90%;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>jquery-popup-overlay example</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="page">
    <header></header>
    <main>
      <p>

      </p>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>

  <section id="popup1">
    <h2>My popup 1</h2>
    <p>popup1</p>
  </section>

  <section id="popup2">
    <h2>My popup 2</h2>
    <p>hello from popup2</p>
    <p>popup2.</p>
  </section>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay@2/jquery.popupoverlay.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When I run your jsfiddle and your interactive snippet, I'm seeing your popup text for 4 seconds before it disappears. Is that what you're trying to do, or do you want it to start with nothing there and then appear after 4 seconds?

Comment: Question is not clear, not clear what you want

Comment: I added a response using a more correct use of the plug-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hide the popup initially and then add another class that makes it visible.

JS

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  $(".popup_content").addClass("active");
}, 4000);
```

CSS

```
.popup_content {
  visibility:hidden;
}
.popup_content.active {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/ninjasoards/ajf0pL1x/2/

Comment: It may not have been clear in the question, but the OP seems to be using the [jQuery Popup Overlay plugin](https://github.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay).

Comment: @GermanyDeutschland Alright, if it works for you. Note that it doesn't make use of the plugin's functionality at all.

Answer (score 1):

The `.popup('show')` method "[m]anually opens a popup".

> **.popup('show')**
>   Manually opens a popup.

I recommend initializing the popup immediately and then triggering the "show" method from your interval function. Here's a demonstration:

```js
let $popup1 = $('#popup1').popup();

setInterval(function() {
  $popup1.popup('show');
}, 500);
```

```css
.popup_content {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-width: 90%;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay@2/jquery.popupoverlay.min.js"></script>

<section id="popup1">
  <h2>My popup 1</h2>
  <p>popup1</p>
</section>
```

---

Alternatively, you can set up a button with a class that references the popup ID.
See the [openelement option](https://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/).

> **openelement**
>   string (CSS selector)
>   Default: '.{popup_id}_open'
>   Enables you to define custom element which will open the popup on click.

```js
$('#popup1').popup();
```

```css
.popup_content {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-width: 90%;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay@2/jquery.popupoverlay.min.js"></script>


<div id="page">
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <button class="popup1_open">Popup 1</button>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
</div>

<section id="popup1">
  <h2>My popup 1</h2>
  <p>popup1</p>
</section>
```

Also check out the sample [CodePen](https://codepen.io/vladimirs/pen/wRapwj) from the [documentation page](https://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/).

Answer (score 1):

You are just Initializing the popup. It by default will be closed when initialized. For manually triggering you should use  `.popup('show')` method. I have updated the [jsfiddle code here](https://jsfiddle.net/zn8cuf67/)

The actual code you need if you want popup's to open after 4 seconds

```
//Initialize
$('#popup1').popup();
$('#popup2').popup({
  pagecontainer: '#page',
  escape: false
});


setTimeout(function(){ 
    //Trigger
    $('#popup1').popup('show');
    $('#popup2').popup('show');
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to instantiate the popups, then with a button (as indicated in the documentation) you can trigger the click event, even if the button is invisible

```js
  $('#popup1').popup({
  pagecontainer: 'body',
  });
  
    $('#popup2').popup({
    pagecontainer: '#page',
    escape: false
  });

setInterval(function() {

  $(".popup2_open").trigger("click")

}, 4000);
```

```css
.popup_content {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-width: 90%;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  background: white;
}

.display-none{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>jquery-popup-overlay example</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="page">
    <header></header>
    <main>
      <p>

      </p>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>

 <button class="popup1_open">Click me! popup 1 </button>
 <button class="popup2_open display-none">button number 2! </button>
<p>The second popup will open after 4 seconds</p>
  <section id="popup1">
    <h2>My popup 1</h2>
    <p>popup1</p>
  </section>

  <section id="popup2">
    <h2>My popup 2</h2>
    <p>hello from popup2</p>
    <p>popup2.</p>
  </section>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay@2/jquery.popupoverlay.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```